# How can I make bash update without restarting it after removing an alias?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

My task is to simply remove an alias and update s.t. the old `alias` does not work. Yes I know there are many `source` commands out there, however it does not seem to work for me this time. 
My setup is as follows; In my `~/.bash_aliases` I made this `alias`:

`alias gali='gedit ~/.bash_aliases;sort ~/.bash_aliases -o ~/.bash_aliases;sbash'`
Where `sbash='source ~/.bashrc'`.

For adding and updating, which works like a charm, but when I remove an alias using this command or manually step-by-step, the bash does not update. How can I make this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` should work

Comment: Yes I know it should work, but it does'nt and I'm wondering why!:)

Comment: @George does that unalias all aliases or just recreate the ali ases it sees and leave the removed aliases as is? I would believe Yaron is correct: unalias it.

Comment: I use `. <path-to-script-file>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove an alias from the `.bash_aliases` it isn't removed from the `bash` aliases.

If you want to have *only* the aliases in the `.bash_aliases` you will need to clean all bash shell aliases, and afterwards loads the aliases from the `.bash_aliases`

**[Clear all Linux / UNIX bash shell aliases](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/clearing-all-bash-aliases-with-unalias-command/)**

If the -a option is given, then remove all alias definitions.

```
$ unalias -a
```

Assuming that all your aliases exists in `~/.bash_aliases` (I suspect that you are using aliases from other sources as well...) you should execute `unalias -a` follows by the command to `source ~/.bash_alises`

Your code should look like this:

```
alias gali='gedit ~/.bash_aliases;sort ~/.bash_aliases -o ~/.bash_aliases;unalias -a; source ~/.bash_aliases'
```